# Footer that is hidden when window is resized?

Tags: css, footer

I have a footer with fixed position that I'm trying to keep on the bottom of the page but also have it to not follow the browser window when I resize it. So if I drag Firefox from the bottom it's hidden.

I have tried relative position, which makes the footer jump up and sit under the header. I have also tried absolute position which I assumed would be the right one to use but it seems to do the same thing as the fixed position.

**CSS :**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
}               
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px; 
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #7a7a7a; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #7a7a7a; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #7a7a7a;
}
#content {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom :45px;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #222;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post a working example in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've solved your problem. You need to use `position: absolute;` like before, but instead of specifying the position/placement from the bottom, you have to specify it from the top like this: `top: 500px;` this way you can insert content above the footer and it also stays where it is even when you resize the browser window!

Edit: After some research I've found that another way is to put the content in a **containing block** (which is a element that is positioned either **relative**, **absolute**, or **fixed**) and then put it at the bottom of the document source, and go from there.

Comment: Yeah that won't really do it unfortunately. I need it to sit in the same position anywhere it's displayed

Comment: You probably have to use some javascript to determine the users browser window height and adjust your css accordingly. Here's a link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp